# Request to migrate this SO question to UI

Tags: discussion, migrate

I'm not a UI expert, but I do like to play around with it and search new techniques and evolution of UI.

This question is one of my favorite, considering UI...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019573/save-icon-still-a-floppy-disk

Can we migrate this question? Is this the right way to request so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating questions from Stack Overflow will probably have to wait until this site is out of beta. If and when that becomes an option, the action will have to take place *on* Stack Overflow. I would suggest leaving a comment over there, or, if you have enough rep, voting to close it as "belongs on UI."

In the mean time, if you see a question on SO that you think would have gotten better answers on this site, you can ask again over here. Link back to the original and leave a comment on the original linking to your new question (h/t @Sruly).

Comment: You can also link that question back to here.